# Embedded Linux. Execute block of code atomically

Tags: c, linux, scheduling, embedded-linux, atomic

Currently, I have a user space application on an embedded linux device (version 2.6.28.10) which is toggling GPIO pins to control some custom hardware. The writes to the GPIO registers occur from separate `pthreads` all of which need access to the device. Most of the time this works fine since there is a `semaphore` preventing multiple threads from accessing the section that does the GPIO writes simultaneously.

The problem is that in the middle of writing to these GPIO registers (about 24 8-bit writes) another thread `will interrupt` the current thread and though the interrupting thread cannot modify the registers due to the semaphore, control is not returned to the thread that is writing to the GPIOs for several milliseconds which, of course, makes the data sent to the external device invalid.

Is there a method in linux to ensure that this set of GPIO writes (taking a total of about 50 usecs) is not interrupted by another thread?

Comment: It strikes me that this is a perfect example of needing a kernel driver... I know of nothing that would *guarantee* this functionality. Bumping thread priority would help, but it's not a guarantee.

Comment: Is this even a guarantee from within a kernel driver though? I thought it was possible for even a section of code in a kernel driver to be interrupted.

Comment: In a kernel driver you can lock against other threads being switched in, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question how this thread interrupts the working thread, and what kind of a thread it is (user space, or kernel space, or an actual interrupt).

If the interrupting thread is a user space thread, you can just have it respect the mutual exclusion semaphore. Another option would be to temporarily raise the priority of the working thread so that the CPU cannot be taken away from it (if such a facility is available).

If the interrupting thread is a kernel space thread, you can try and use a semaphore implementation that can be invoked from the kernel as well (System V semaphores). These are heavier though.

If the interrupting thread is actually an interrupt then you would need to build a kernel component that is invoked by your user space threads, which in turn disables the interrupts in the critical section. This will affect the performance negatively.

Comment: These threads are currently user-space `pthreads` and the interruption is done by the scheduler allowing other threads to run. The problem is not that the other threads are not respecting the semaphore, but that the scheduler is giving other threads time during a section of code that needs to be executed atomically. And what I mean by that is the GPIO writes take 50 usec and those 50 usecs need to be contiguous on the processor, not 25 usec here and 25 usec a few ms later

Comment: I see. In that case you should look into what kind of real-time support your kernel has (https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RT_PREEMPT_HOWTO). Or implement a kernel space component that you call into (heavier).